# Monitoring Amazon RDS with pgtop

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, amazon-rds, monitoring

I recently migrated a Postgres database to Amazon RDS and I am lacking a good live monitoring tool. I tried pgtop, but I can't get it to work on Amazon. I can see the header with the DB statistics (CPU, I/O, memory, etc.) but the query list is completely empty.

So, does anyone have any experience with pgtop specifically on RDS for PostgreSQL? I would like to know what queries are running, cpu usage, queries state, etc.

Comment: Are you database superuser?

Comment: @DanielVérité I am not, that is probably what causes the problem. Amazon does not allow me to be a postgres [superuser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html) in RDS: `The rds_superuser role is similar to the PostgreSQL superuser role (customarily named postgres in local instances) but with some restrictions`

Comment: @nmat hope the links I have added here will help you https://pganalyze.com/docs/install/01_enabling_pg_stat_statements ,https://pganalyze.com/,https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=548724

Comment: @PathumAnjana Thanks for the links. I didn't know about `pg_stat_statements`, looks very interesting. Another tool I found that uses that extension is [PoWA](https://dalibo.github.io/powa/). I will look into it.

Comment: @nmat according to them The pg_stat_statements module provides a means for tracking execution statistics of all SQL statements executed by a server. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/pgstatstatements.html

Comment: @JackDouglas I added two words, is it specific enough now? :)  Please note that this seems a real pain point with PostgreSQL.

Comment: @dezso I'm not sure - I've edited to focus entirely on pgtop but it looks like the simple answer now is "no", so too localized.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that applies to Amazon RDS, but a possible reason for getting an empty list of queries with `pgtop` is when using a version older than 3.7.0 (released in August 2013) against a 9.2 or newer PostgreSQL instance.

I just noticed this with the ptop 3.6.2 package that currently ships with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I guess this may be also not fixed in other distributions.

The empty list problem occurs with older versions of `pgtop` because they expect the postgres process ID in  `pg_stat_statements.procpid`, and this column was renamed to `pg_stat_statements.pid` in PG 9.2.

This is combined with `pgtop` being unhelpful by not reporting any error when its SQL command fails. Instead it just displays a blank list of processes. The problematic query can be spotted in the server's log.

Comment: I just confirmed that I am using pgtop version 3.7.0. I believe that the pgtop problem is related to the lack of permissions from the amazon rds user. But thank you for your answer